# Website not appearing as it is on mobile. How to solve this problem?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, mobile-website, elementor

I am editing the home page of my website with the help of Elementor. On the home page, there is a headline in the left column and an image to==in the right column. The website is appearing correct on the desktop.
[Dekstop view. Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmGB1.jpg)

But when I open the website on mobile, Tthe image should appear above the headline. But it is appearing beside the headline. Therefore the website looks ugly.

[mobile view. Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXVG0.jpg)

I am using Astra Free Theme I am using the following plugins: A3 lazy load, wp asset cleanup, swift performance, Akismet, Elementor, essential addons for Elementor, GDPR consent, Ninja forms, Lite speed cache, user profile picture, My WordPress version is 5.6.1 My PHP version is 7.4

javascript

Comment: Edit column and make column width 100% for both column

Answer (score 0):

you should change the column width for text and the picture to 100%
if the picture went below the text.
in that case, select the whole section, then go to the "advanced" tab, in the responsive tab, select reverse columns for tablet and mobile.

let me know if there was any problem with that.